git gives hint to "dispable or modify the sparsity rules" when "worktree is not sparse"
I rarely use a sparse checkout (more likely to use a shallow clone). I almost always use a .gitignore file. That file is sometimes configured to ignore directories or files that are already part of the repository, so secrets or changes for local environments are kept out of git status.
If I need to update one such ignored template file, then I thought I had always used git add --force but now that yields:

The following paths and/or pathspecs matched paths that exist
outside of your sparse-checkout definition, so will not be
updated in the index

Followed by the hints:

If you intend to update such entries, try one of the following:

Use the --sparse option.
Disable or modify the sparsity rules.

Disable this message with "git config advice.updateSparsePath false"

I tried commenting out parts of and then the entire .gitignore. With that I again tried git add --force and also git add --sparse.
I tried investigating git-sparse-checkout details, but stopped when git sparse-checkout list said:

fatal: this worktree is not sparse

This is coming from git 2.44 but I am very used to git 1.8.

TL;DR; git sparse-checkout disable

With my online searching failing me, I went back to looking at the manual for git-sparse-checkout. I use an eternal bash history configuration, so I knew it was unlikely that I had ever used any command with "sparse" anything on this machine. Despite that, I decided (after making a backup) to try git sparse-checkout disable. Surprisingly, even though "this work tree is not sparse" it said:

warning: The following paths were already present and thus not updated despite sparse patterns:

Then listed several files, including the one I was trying to change. A regular git add worked on the file after that.
Afterwards, even with the .gitignore enabled again, the modifications to those files are showing in git status (when before running git sparse-checkout disable they were not). I assume that means I must have configured something specifically for them in the past. Something related to sparse-checkout since the git hints suggested it and I was able to disable that configuration from it, but not specifically done as a sub-command of it (and not done from another command with flag like --sparse) since "sparse" was not in my command history (there are cases where bash history does not get written, so I guess it is not completely ruled out).
